# Git Hooks Remote Work Tree Commit

Tags: git, web, deployment

At the moment I am using a `post-receive` hook to checkout the most recent commit and deploy that to my web site. And that works great.
But I wanted to try and integrate [micropub](https://www.w3.org/TR/micropub/) into my workflow. But posting with [micropub](https://www.w3.org/TR/micropub/)  obviously changes the content of my web server and I'd like that new content to find its way back into my Git repository. Otherwise it will be overwritten with the post-receive hook every time I push something to the repo.

Right now I am using this `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
WEB_DIR=/home/user/public_html/pathtoblog

# remove any untracked files and directories
git --work-tree=${WEB_DIR} clean -fd

# force checkout of the latest deploy
git --work-tree=${WEB_DIR} checkout master --force
```

Is there a way to modify this so it does not clean `WEB_DIR` but instead commit/merge any changes from `WEB_DIR` before checkout?